# Unable to enable hibernate filter in spring EntityManager using spring aop

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, aop, spring-aop, hibernate-filters

I'm trying to enable a hibernate filter through spring `EntityManager` by tyring to pointcut a service implementation method annotated with custom annotation `@TenantAware` and add `@Around` advise to that method. I want to enable custom filter which adds a differentiator `where tenant_id = :tenantId` on all entities that extend a `BaseEntity`. Hence I created the custom annotation and using it on `@Transactional` methods where it is required.  It is intercepting the method successfully but the variable values when I log them are showing up empty and neither is the filter being set.

The project is a spring-boot 2 application and I'm using spring aop for creating the aspect. I'm using Hibernate 5 as the JPA implementation provider.

Load time weaving of the `SimpleJpaRepository.class` is not possible since it does not expose a noarg constructor.

This is my `TenantFilterAdvisor` class.

```
package org.foo.bar.advisors;

@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TenantFilterAdvisor {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public TenantFilterAdvisor() {
        log.debug("###########################################################################");
        log.debug("###################### Tenant Advisor Filter Started ######################");
        log.debug("###########################################################################");
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(org.foo.bar.TenantAware)")
    public void methodAnnotatedWithTenantAware() {
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public * * (..))")
    public void allPublicMethods() {

    }

    @Around(value = "methodAnnotatedWithTenantAware() && allPublicMethods()")
    public Object enableTenantFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

        log.debug("###########################################################################");
        log.debug("###################### Before enabling tenant filter ######################");
        log.debug("###########################################################################");

        if (null != entityManager) {

            log.debug("Tenant filter name: ", "tenantFilter");
            log.debug("Tenant filter property: ", "tenantId");
            log.debug("Setting tenant id to: ", new Long(10));

            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
            Filter filter = session.enableFilter("tenantFilter");
            filter.setParameter("tenantId", new Long(10));

        }


        Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

        // Code to disable the hibernate filter goes here.
        log.debug("###########################################################################");
        log.debug("###################### After disabling tenant filter ######################");
        log.debug("###########################################################################");

        return result;

    }

}
```

The relevant part of service interface and implementation class is

```
public interface InventoryService {
    Inventory getInventoryById(Long id);
}
```

```
@Service
public class InventoryServiceImpl implements InventoryService {

    @Autowired
    private InventoryRepository repo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @TenantAware
    public Inventory getInventoryById(Long id) {
       LOG.debug("getInventoryById() called  with: id = {}", id);
        final Optional<Inventory> inventoryOp = repo.findById(id);

        if (inventoryOp.isPresent()) {
            return inventoryOp.get();
        } else {
            throw new InventoryNotFoundException(String.format(MESSAGE_INVENTORY_NOT_FOUND_FOR_ID, id));
        }
    }
}
```

The repository interface is

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface InventoryRepository extends BaseRepository<Inventory, Long> {  
}
```

The BaseRepository interface extends JpaRepository.

And the aspect configuration class is

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.foo.bar.advisors"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AOPConfig {
}
```

And finally the relevant MappedSuperClass which is inherited by other classes has the filter defined as

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@FilterDef(
        name = "tenantFilter",
        parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantId", type = "long")
)
@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantId")
public abstract class BaseTransactionalEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
    private Long tenantId;

}
```

Here is the cutom annotation class if you need the detail

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
public @interface TenantAware {
}
```

I need the hibernate filter to be enabled in session and disabled after the proceeding join point completes the execution. But it is not so. What am I missing?

Comment: Ofcourse they aren't logger. You are missing the `{}` placeholder in your log message.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get that. But what about the filter not being enabled on the entity manager?

Comment: How are you obtaining the data. YOu only show the service but not the actual implementation using an entitymanager or repository.

Comment: I have a repository interface that extends spring `JpaRepository` interface. I'm relying on spring `SimpleJpaRepository` to provide the implementation. Otherwise I'll have to implement my own repository implementation ground up which beats the purpose. If needed I can post the repository interface here but it's an empty interface as I said.

Comment: `findById` calls `entityManager.find` and filters don't work in that case. They only work in case of queries.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Hibernate Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter) filters only apply to entity queries not to direct fetching. In your code you are doing a direct fetch through `findById` which translates to `entityManager.find` and is thus a direct fetch.

You could override the Spring JPA repository and reimplement the `findById` to be an entity query instead of a direct fetch, to workaround this issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I wish there was an easy way to do something so trivial. Now I guess I'll have to provide my own implementation for all the methods just to apply that filter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and proven to be working) way without AOP is using `TransactionManagerCustomizers`:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateFilterConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager() {
            @Override
            @NonNull
            protected EntityManager createEntityManagerForTransaction() {
                final EntityManager entityManager = super.createEntityManagerForTransaction();
                Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                session.enableFilter("tenantFilter").setParameter("tenantId", new Long(10));
                return entityManager;
            }
        };
        transactionManagerCustomizers.ifAvailable((customizers) -> customizers.customize(transactionManager));

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```